# How to convert numpy array to 16 bytes per element bytearray

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Numpy does not support a `dtype` of `int128` which I need. So I've created an array of objects to go around it like so:

```
def to_bytes(x):
    return x.to_bytes(16, 'little')

vec = numpy.frompyfunc(to_bytes, 1,1)
buffer =vec(array)
```

However, now I do not know how to convert this ndarray to single python `bytearray`

My other solution was using a loop and it worked. However, I am afraid this is not the most efficient way to do so. Any suggestions are welcome.

```
buff_size=1024
buffer = memoryview(bytearray(buff_size * 16))
for i in range(len(array)):
     pos = i * 16
     buffer[pos:pos + 16] = array[i].to_bytes(16, 'little')
```